# Python: MongoDB update by timestamp not working as expected

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, python-datetime

first of all, I want to say that I'm a total noob when it comes to python but yeah actually I'm currently trying to fix a smaller problem within a python script.

So I'm using mongo db to store some reservation data in a mongo db collection called `reservations`.

Example of the collection data:

```json
        {
           _id: ObjectId("5f2820a2f8279f6a284d4f02")
          eventId: "AQMkAGFlMTBmNWMwLTRhNjEtNDFhMS1iOWM3LTc4YjNlYTg5YWIxMQAARgAAA3tu3bjjJ0..."
          startTime: 2020-08-03T12:13:00.000+00:00,
          endTime: 2020-08-03T12:32:00.000+00:00,
          finished: false
        }
```

Now I'm trying to update all expired event data using the following code:

```py
        @catch_exceptions()
        def finish_reservations():
            now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0, second=0)
            logging.info("Finishing expired reservations...")
            if db.reservations.count_documents({ "finished": {"$exists": False} }) > 0:
                db.reservations.update_many({ "finished": {"$exists": False} }, {"$set": {"finished": True}})
    
            for reservation in db.reservations.find({"endTime": {"$lt":now}, "finished": {"$eq": False}}):
                db.reservations.update_one(
                    { 'eventId': reservation['eventId'] },
                    { '$set': { 'finished': True } }
                )
```

So what I try to achieve is the following:

If there is any data in the collection which does not already have the field `finished` existant, add it with the value 'true'. After that, check for events that aren't finished yet and finish them if their `endTime` date and time timestamp is lower than the `now` date and time timestamp.

The problem: The solution above is not actually updating all expected data entries ... The example above is not updated even though the `finished` state is `false` and the `endTime` is def. lower than `now` (`datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 8, 14, 24)`). Other entries were updated correctly ...

Does anybody have an advice on this?

Comment: `{ 'id': reservation['id'] }` here must be `_id`, starting with underscore

Comment: And probably you'd better get rid of the loop and use update_many

Comment: Sorry, there was a little bug inside my code sample, I'm using  the `eventId` field, not the `_id` field for the update. And yeah, I'll change it and use update_many. Maybe that helps :o

Comment: I've got rid of the loop and changed it to `db.reservations.update_many({ "endTime": { "$lt":now }, "finished": { "$eq": False } }, { '$set': { 'finished': True } })` but unfortunately, the behavior didn't change at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates and timezones are a massive beartrap in python and pymongo.

When using a `date` BSON type in MongoDB, dates are always stored in UTC. So you might think that using  `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` would make sense - but sadly not.

`utcnow()` returns a timezone naive datetime. This means it will give different results in different timezones. I suspect this will be your problem.

If you want to take the gamble out if ensure your [MongoClient connection](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html) has `tz_aware=True` and use timezone aware dates, e.g.

```
import pytz
now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
```

Comment: Wow, I could have searched for hours and hours. :D This actually worked. The data is updated correctly now! Thank you very much. I'll gather some further information about this in the interwebz.